# How is this Cope Reaction forming Ethene as major product?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, nitro-compounds

I have been asked to find the major product of the reaction:
[image]

As this a case of pyrolysis of $3^{\circ}$ Amine Oxide (or, in other words, *Cope Reaction*), I figured there are two possible products hexene and hex-2-ene. Therefore, hex-2-ene should be the major product as it is the more substituted alkene.

But the solution to the question states that the major product is Ethene ($\ce{H_2C=CH_2}$). I have no idea how that is even possible.

Here is how I came to the conclusion that hex-2-ene will be the major product (which is basically the standard Cope reaction mechanism):
[image]
Please provide clarification on this.

Comment: This looks like an error. You can get propene (probably the major product) and the two hexenes you mentioned, but I can see no way of getting ethene.

Comment: @Waylander This must be an error then. Errors are not rare in organic chemistry question banks, or at least, that is the case with my book.

Comment: Hex-1-ene would be the major product. There are more no. of hydrogens on the 1° carbon. Therefore, at a particular instant, hydrogens of this carbon would be antiperiplanar to O- in more number of molecules of the sample. Hence the major product